# How do I deploy Python on Android Studio?

Tags: python, android-studio

I am using visual studio code to work on my python and Android studio for the android app.
I have create a machine learning to recommend user restaurants based on their favourite restaurant. I use **sklearn.feature_extraction** and **cosine_similarity** to give the recommendation.[pythoncode1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIKWM.png)

The next step is to deploy it to Android App which I am not sure how. I have seen others deploying their tensorflow keras model on Android App but mine isn't, so how should I proceed next? [pythoncode2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmxkh.png)